# Gulp useref build files in root folder

Tags: gulp

I'm using yeoman's gulp webapp generator on a project, for some special reason, I need to generate files in root folder rather than in "dist" folder, but I have some problems with the path, here are my code below.

In HTML:

```
<!-- build:js ../scripts/vendor/modernizr.js -->
<script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

In gulpfile.js

```
// HTML
gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
      .pipe($.useref())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('')) // I removed 'dist' here
      .pipe($.size());
});
```

It's exactly generate a scripts folder and the index.html in root folder, but the script path in index.html is wrong.

```
<script src="../scripts/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
```

I can't find any mention in gulpfile.js, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [gulp-replace-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace-path) plugin

You could try something like this

```
.pipe($.replacePath('../', '')
.pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think you will need to manually change the `src` attribute in the script tags of `index.html` as I don't think it will be doing it dynamically for you without having a proper look.

It's a simple change anyway. Just go into `index.html` and remove `../` from that `src` attribute.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For grunt i've done something like this..

```
replace: {
            prod: {
                src: ['../prod/**/css/*.css'],
                overwrite: true,
                replacements: [{
                    from: "../../../inc/",
                    to: "../../../../inc/"**
        }]
    }
}
```